# Java Import package into running application

Tags: java, swing

I want to import a package into a compiled and running java application.
Im making a modular swing application that can load all JPanel from another Class. The class name is loaded from text file(and can be change).

```
String[] className;
BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wb.conf"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (line != null) {
            if(!line.substring(0, 1).equals("#")){ //not comment
                if(lineNumber == 0) //first line is number of class
                    classNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);
                else //second is the class name
                    className = line.split(";", classNumber+1);
                lineNumber++;
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
```

I try and i can load a class with this example, but the loaded class must in the package when i compile that:

```
String aClass = "testPackage.CallableMethod", aMethod = "aMethod"; 
    Class[] params = new Class[] {String.class}; 
    Object[] args = new Object[] {new String("Hello")} ;
    Class[] c = new Class[2];
    Method[] m = new Method[2];
    for(int i =0; i<2; i++){
        c[i] = Class.forName(aClass);
        m[i] = c[i].getDeclaredMethod(aMethod, params);
        Object oi = c[i].newInstance();
        Object r = m[i].invoke(oi, args);
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
```

And my question is. Can i import (or anything else) another *.class or *.jar file into a compiled java app.
And if yes. How?

Comment: What do you mean by _import_? Of course you can take arbitrary Java source code or classes and compile/load with a custom class loader - but what then? You can only invoke methods on it via reflection. Depending on what exactly it is you are doing, you may need to look into [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) - but that may be somewhat above your level.

Comment: @wero ok sorry my mystake. thats "aMethod" is the method name in class "testPackage.CallableMethod".

Comment: @BoristheSpider than you. I need something like "custom class loader" and of corse also look at OSGi. btw. i think im good in java but my english is horrible. Thank you

Comment: is your test method ìn `testPackage.CallableMethod` not public?

Comment: This example work for me. but i want a help, how can i import another *.class or *.jar after i compile and run the program.

Comment: Look into the [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). Note that the URL can point to local files.